# How to store booleans in a custom facet?

Tags: xdb, contact-facets

Does Sitecore support store booleans in a custom facet?

I have the following ***interfaces***:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;

    namespace MySite.Models.Facets
    {
        public interface IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement : IElement
        {
            DateTime Sent { get; set; }
            string ContactType { get; set; }
            string Message { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

---

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{

    public interface IAdditionalInfoFacet : IFacet
    {
        string Company { get; set; }
        string RevenueRange { get; set; }
        string Industry { get; set; }
        string SubIndustry { get; set; }
        IElementCollection<IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement> Communications { get; }
        bool OptIn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

and the following ***classes***:

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;

namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AdditionalInfoCommunicationElement: Element, IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement
    {
        private const string FIELD_SENT = "Sent";
        private const string FIELD_CONTACT_TYPE = "Contact Type";
        private const string FIELD_MESSAGE = "Message";

        public AdditionalInfoCommunicationElement()
        {
            EnsureAttribute<DateTime>(FIELD_SENT);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_CONTACT_TYPE);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_MESSAGE);
        }

        public DateTime Sent
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<DateTime>(FIELD_SENT); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_SENT, value); }
        }

        public string ContactType
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_CONTACT_TYPE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_CONTACT_TYPE, value); }
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_MESSAGE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_MESSAGE, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```cs
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework;
using System;
namespace MySite.Models.Facets
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AdditionalInfoFacet : Facet, IAdditionalInfoFacet
    {
        public const string FACET_NAME = "Company Info";
        private const string FIELD_COMPANY = "Company";
        private const string FIELD_INDUSTRY = "Industry";
        private const string FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY = "SubIndustry";
        private const string FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE = "RevenueRange";
        private const string FIELD_OPT_IN = "OptIn";
        public AdditionalInfoFacet()
        {
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_COMPANY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_INDUSTRY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE);
            EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_OPT_IN);
            EnsureCollection<IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement>(FACET_NAME);
        }
        public string Company
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_COMPANY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_COMPANY, value); }
        }
        public string Industry
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_INDUSTRY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_INDUSTRY, value); }
        }
        public string SubIndustry
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_SUB_INDUSTRY, value); }
        }
        public string RevenueRange
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<string>(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_REVENUE_RANGE, value); }
        }
        public IElementCollection<IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement> Communications
        {
            get
            {
                return GetCollection<IAdditionalInfoCommunicationElement>(FACET_NAME);
            }
        }
        public bool OptIn
        {
            get { return GetAttribute<bool>(FIELD_OPT_IN); }
            set { SetAttribute(FIELD_OPT_IN, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**But the following code snippet:**

```cs
if (registration.ForceOptIn == true || registration.ShowOptIn == false || (registration.ShowOptIn == true && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(registration.OptIn)))
{
    additionalInfo.OptIn = true;
}
else
{
    additionalInfo.OptIn = false;
}
```

**Throws the following error:**

```
> Exception: System.InvalidCastException Message: Unable to cast object
> of type
> 'Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelAttributeMember`1[System.String]'
> to type
> 'Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.IModelAttributeMember`1[System.Boolean]'.
> Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Model    at
> Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.Element.SetAttribute[TValue](String
> name, TValue value)    at
> MySite.Analytics.ContactManagement.RegisterContact(Registration
> registration) in
> C:\SRC\Main\Sitecore\MySite.Analytics\ContactManagement.cs:line 127
```

To me it look like everywhere I reference OptIn I am using a bool, but this error seems to indicate I am using a string somewhere?

I am running `Sitecore 8.1 Update 2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `AdditionalInfoFacet` constructor, change this line:

```cs
EnsureAttribute<string>(FIELD_OPT_IN);
```

To this:

```cs
EnsureAttribute<bool>(FIELD_OPT_IN);
```

You need to register your boolean attribute with the correct type.

Comment: Ok, it is time to go to bed or more coffee.   I looked at that code for like an hour trying to find what it was.   :-(

Comment: I feel like there could have been a more helpful error message here!